What are Advances used for in Eat the Reich?
On the Eat the Reich character sheet, there are three things listed under the heading "Advances". They look a lot like abilities, but there's a checkbox next to them, and as far as I can tell, they're never mentioned anywhere in the rulebook. What are they for? How do they work?
I'm prepared to accept I'm just bad at reading and missed the crucial paragraph(s), but I've been over the book multiple times looking for them and I can't find it if that's the case!

You turn them on when you get a drink of the good stuff.
And by "the good stuff", I mean "Nazi robot blood"*:

In EAT THE REICH, the greatest weapons in Hitler’s arsenal are the living tools of destruction known as Übermenschen. These supernaturally-augmented warriors have a chance of going toe-to-toe with a vampire and not dying – some are powerful enough to maybe even kill the vampire. That makes them a pretty big deal. Also, their supernatural augmentation means that their blood is jam-packed with occult power, and drinking it allows a player character to choose one of the advances on their sheet and activate it.
-- "Übermenschen", Eat the Reich p. 43

*okay, so the stahlsoldat is just one of four potential such encounters but it's got the easiest punch-up don't @ me
Given how there are three available advances and three potential such fights before the big finale (which also counts as one), this should probably be read as "one advance as a reward after the fight, or turned on early by drinking blood during it" rather than, say, "one advance per die you spend on feeding during the fight".
